# How to compare an input() with a variable(list)

Tags: python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

(Im using python on Jupiter Notebook 5.7.8)

I have a project in which are 3 lists, and a list(list_of_lists) that refer to those 3.
I want my program to receive an input, compare this input to the content of my "list_of_lists" and if find a match I want to store the match in another variable for later use.

Im just learning, so here is the code I wrote:

```
first = ["item1", "item2","item3"]    
second = ["item4","item5","item6"]    

list1 = [first,second]    
list2 = ["asd","asd","asd"]    
list_of_lists = [list1,list2]    

x = input("Which list are you going to use?: ")    

for item in list_of_lists:    
    if item == x:    
        match = item    
        print(match)    
        print('There was a match')    
    else:    
        print('didnt match')
```

I expect a match but it always output "the didnt match", 
I assume it fail to compare the contect of the input with the list inside the list_of lists. The question is also why and how to do it properly(if possible), thanks.

Comment: *"Which list are you going to use?: "* What's your answer for this?

Comment: Hint: Add a `print(item)` at the beginning of your for loop and you'll see that `item` isn't what you think it is

Comment: Austin the answer I put is list1, the in order to invoke the first list

Comment: @SyntaxVoid I see what you meant, I didnt have much time last week, but now i come to a kind of solution, I will put it in the comment below any help would be nice

Answer (score 0):

`input` in *python3* returns a string. if you want to convert it into a list, use `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` or your own parsing method.

```
list_str = input("Which list are you going to use?: ") 
user_list = ast.literal_eval(list_str)
assert isinstance(user_list, list)
...
# do your thing...
```

Comment: Hi @Yoav Glazner, that was not what i desire my progam to do. I wanted an input to be compared to a list in order to find a match

Answer (score 0):

So here i tried this code, and it does what i desire, I dont know if its too rudimentary and if there is another way to achieve this.
Here I use a second list to catch the moment when there is a match, after I give to that list the value of my true list and from there print it to be used.

I was wondering if there is a way to take out of the ressults the symbols "[]" and the quotes '', so I can have a clean text format, thanks for the help

```
first = ["item1", "item2","item3"]    
second = ["item4","item5","item6"]    

list1 = [first,second]    
list2 = ["asd","asd","asd"]    
list3 = ["qwe","qwe","qwe"]    
list_of_lists = [list1,list2,list3]    
reference_list = ["list1","list2","list3"]    
count = -1    

x = input('Which list are you going to use? ')    

for item in reference_list:    
    count += 1    
    if x == item:    
        reference_list = list_of_lists    
        print(reference_list[count])
```